# Septīmus or septĭmus?

Tags: vowel-quantity, numbers, romance-languages

In the past, I'd vaguely assumed that the word for "seventh" was *sept**ī**mus*, because we see an *i* instead of an *e* in the Romance languages (Italian *settimo*, French *septime*, etc).

However, Lewis and Short say it was *sept**ĭ**mus*—and that it actually alternated with *sept**ŭ**mus*, giving us even more confirmation of the short vowel.

If it was a short vowel, though, how did we end up with *i* in Romance? And if it was long, how did it alternate with *u* in Latin?

Comment: [Vergil uses the word four times](https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=%23septim+%5Bverg%5D), unambiguously with a short vowel. I can write an answer collecting metric evidence for the quantity if you want, but I feel that your main focus is elsewhere.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Much appreciated, but indeed, my question is less "how do we know" and more "how do we square the Romance evidence with the Classical evidence".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

French *septime* is clearly marked as a learned form by the use of *-pt-.* As a learned word, it provides no evidence to the length of the Latin vowel. The TLFi mentions an old form *[sedme, setme](https://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/septi%C3%A8me)* inherited from *septĭmus.*

The stress pattern of Italian *sèttimo* indicates that the second syllable did not originally have long ī. I'm not sure whether this word is a regular descendant from Latin or a learned borrowing, like French *septime*. In Italian, the vowel *[e] was raised to /i/ in unstressed syllables in a number of contexts: it seems this was regular at least in [pretonic position](https://www.reddit.com/r/linguistics/comments/kbbwdz/comment/gfj66fv/). I don't know whether raising of *[e] could also be found in posttonic syllables, but I think it could, based on forms like *uomini* < *hominēs* and *gomito* < *cubitum* that show Romance sound changes in other parts of the word.